# Append Multiple Dataframes and Comments Above the Dataframe into One Worksheet using Gspread and python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am looking for a solution where I can append multiple dataframes and some comments above the dataframe into one worksheet in google sheet using gspread.

Following is the example of what I need, can anyone help me with this.

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])

data1 = {'Name':['Renault', 'Maruti', 'Honda'], 'Ratings':[9, 8, 5]}  
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)  

data2 = [{'A': 10, 'B': 20}, {'x':10, 'y': 20}]  
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 

comments = ['Dataframe 1: ', 'Dataframe 2: ', 'Dataframe 3: ']
```

[image]

**Edit:**
It is some how identical to this code, but it is in excel, i need the same using gspread.

```
  dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3] 
  comments_1 = ['Dataframe 1: ', 'Dataframe 2: ', 'Dataframe 3: '] 
  with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay', mode='a') as writer:
    for dataframe, comment in zip(dfs, comments_1): 
      pd.Series(comment).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_name, 
        startrow=1, startcol=0, index=False, header=False) 
      dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_name, startrow=1, startcol=0)
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving from your showing script to your expected output image? Because I think that the values of your showing script are different from your expected output situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: No, it's ok. The logic is, I need to append those dataframes into google spread sheet with the comments one after another vertically. I am using gspread for this purpose. I have added a worksheet and appended a dataframe though, but still need to figure out how to do the same with multiple dataframes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the logic for achieving your expected situation from your showing script and values. For example, in your value, `['juli', 14]` is used. But, in your result, it seems that `['juli', 14]` is required to be converted to `['nick', 14]`. And, `'Honda City'` is required to be converted to `'Honda'`? And `{'x':100, 'y': 200}` is required to converted to `{'x':10, 'y': 20}`? I cannot understand the logic for achieving your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: And also, in your goal, it seems that you want to put the values using gspread. In this case, can I think of that you have already prepared (Authorization for using Sheets API and Drive API) to use Sheets API with gspread?

Comment: Pardon me for my data. It needed a little change and i have changed it. I have completed the authorization part. All things are doing pretty well using a single dataframe but i need to append multiple dataframes one after another, kindly have a look at the piece of code into the edit section.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misundetstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
import gspread
import pandas as pd

# --- This is from your question.
data = [["tom", 10], ["nick", 15], ["juli", 14]]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age"])

data1 = {"Name": ["Renault", "Maruti", "Honda"], "Ratings": [9, 8, 5]}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = [{"A": 10, "B": 20}, {"x": 10, "y": 20}]
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

comments = ["Dataframe 1: ", "Dataframe 2: ", "Dataframe 3: "]
# ---

# Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3]
values = []
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df = df.fillna("")
    values.append([comments[i]])
    values.extend([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
    values.append([""])

# Put the array to Spreadsheet using gspread.
client = ### # Please use your gspread client.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
sheet.update("A1", values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this script is run, the values are put to "Sheet1" of Spreadsheet of `spreadsheetId`.

#### Note:

- From your reply, this sample script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values to Spreadsheet using Sheets API with gspread. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [update](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking for this only.